# Excel - average on condition whilst changing values

Tags: excel

[image]

I am trying to calculate the average of values based on various conditions: e.g. "a", but I want the value to be capped at a set value. E.g. say we cap the value column at 1500, it would look like this:

[image]

I can do the formula for this quite easily, e.g. using

```
=AVERAGE(IF($B$5:$B$8>=1500,1500,$B$5:$B$8))
```

which works. However, I want to repeat this average formula but for the data filtered for subset "a" and subset "b"

so the average on filtered "a" should be (1000+1500)/2 = 1250, and for "b" it will be 1500. Is there any way to do this for a formula?

Comment: If you don't want to use a helper column, you could try this clunky formula: `=(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5="a"),--(B2:B5<1500)*B2:B5)+SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5="a"),--(B2:B5>=1500)*1500))/COUNTIF(A2:A5,"a")`

Comment: will give this a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in one relatively simple-to-understand formula with no helper columns, you can use a `(SUMIFS(<cap) + cap*COUNTIFS(>=cap) / COUNTIFS` to calculate an average over a capped subset:

```
=(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"a",B:B,"<1500")+1500*COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",B:B,">=1500"))/COUNTIFS(A:A,"a")
```

This:

- sums all `B` if `A = "a"` and `B < 1500`
- counts all `B` if `A = "a"` and `B >= 1500`, then multiplies by 1500
- adds these together to get the capped totals for `B` where `A = "a"`
- divides by count of `A = "a"`

Or to put the threshold in a separate cell, you have to combine it with the condition using `&`:

```
=(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"a",B:B,"<"&D5)+D5*COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",B:B,">="&D5))/COUNTIFS(A:A,"a")
```

---

Excel is gaining `LAMBDA` and [`MAP` functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) - as of Feb 2022 it's in the Office Insiders program - which will probably give a much neater solution when it becomes generally available.

Something like:

```
=AVERAGEIF(MAP(B:B,LAMBDA(x, MIN(x,1500)),A:A,"a")
```

---

If helper columns are an option you can take a simpler approach:

In another column `X`, put the formula `=MIN(@B:B,1500)`

Then you can make averages by category:

```
=SUMIFS(X:X, A:A, "a") / COUNTIFS(A:A, "a")
=SUMIFS(X:X, A:A, "b") / COUNTIFS(A:A, "b")
```

This column `X` could be the next free column on your main sheet i.e. column C, another column on that sheet, or a column on a different (maybe hidden) sheet.

Comment: Thanks but need this without a helper column as the 1500 will change

Comment: You need to see different caps simultaneously? Could have multiple helper columns, and/or `=MIN(@B:B, CapValue)` and put the ~1500 value in a cell named `CapValue`?

Comment: Yeah I would need multiple helper columsn with this approach which I want to avoid that (as I have about 30 CapValues to work through)

Comment: @user33484 It might be useful for you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71053531/edit) to provide a more representative example of your data. Other wise it feels like you are moving the goalpost.

Comment: @user33484 I've updated the answer with a single-cell solution (an amoeba?)